# converting DLL file of crio 9074 with vxworks os to .out

Tags: dll, labview, vxworks

I have crio 9074 with vxworks os and i downloaded dll library on my pc and i need to convert this library to .out in order to read it (crio 9074).

When i upload the dll library on crio and run labview code the vi gave an error(hex 0x436) failed to upload shared library

Comment: Do you have the source code for this DLL? Without it, it is not possible.